# How do I disable nginx sending messages to syslog?

Tags: nginx, syslog

My nginx sends lots of messages to syslog, but I don't need them.
In my nginx.conf:

```
      error_log  /var/log/nginx-error.log  notice;
        ......
      server {
      access_log  off;
      location /
      {
         .... 
        }
      }
```

but, in my `/var/log/message`
you see

```
Nov 22 23:25:09 cache3 nginx: 2011/11/22 23:25:09 [error] 3437#0: *32172530         kevent() reported about an closed connection (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET http://www.igoido012.com//vk HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http:////vk", host: "www.igoido012.com", referrer: "http://www.baidu.com/"
Nov 22 23:25:09 cache3 nginx: 2011/11/22 23:25:09 [error] 3437#0: *32099531 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET http://t.web2.qq.com/channel/poll?msg_id=0&clientid=431509&t=1321975433305 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://:80/channel/poll?msg_id=0&clientid=431509&t=1321975433305", host: "t.web2.qq.com", referrer: "http://t.web2.qq.com/proxy.html?v=20110331001"
```

How can I prevent nginx sending messages to my syslog?

Comment: This seems to be an old question, but, FWIIW, the above error messages appear to be from the `error_log`, not from the `access_log`, so, changing the `access_log` will naturally not have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware that nginx would send to syslog without patching:

http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules#Third_party_patches

So, I assume you have a custom build of nginx.  Take a look at the patch source for hints on how to configure that:

https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_syslog_patch

If you're running a straight nginx, then something else is putting those log entries into syslog.

Comment: On FreeBSD it's an option when you run 'make config.' Maybe that's what OP did. Just like I, which is why I found this post. :-)